# Qtwayland eglfs input does't work without root

Tags: qt, qml, qtwayland

I'm trying to run a qtwayland compositor, mouse and keyboard does't work in eglfs platform unless I run the program as root.

The problem is I need to start a wayland session with that compositor and I can't run that with root access, I also tried normal qt programs and their input does't work with `-platform eglfs`.

How can I solve that problem?

I'm also using Qt version 5.12.10.

Comment: What does "normal qt programs" mean?

Comment: @JarMan QtQuick programs

Comment: Do you mean non-wayland applications?

Comment: So wayland really has nothing to do with your question. The user input is broken whether you use wayland or not.

Comment: @JarMan No, I actually mean window applications that gets created when you start a new project

Comment: @JarMan you're right I deleted wayland tag.

Comment: I believe this is related to eglfs platform plugin not having any native input source, usually the X window system or parent Wayland compositor would handle that, and raw keyboard data can't be accessed by a non-root user. It's a linux permissions thing.